# Integral as a Beta function

Tags: definite-integrals, beta-function

> Is there a way to express integrals like $$\int_0^1 x^{-a} (1+cx)^{1-a} \text dx$$ as a Beta function, where $c$ is positive (or negative) constant and $a>1$?

I tried to use the substitution
\begin{equation} u = \left[{\dfrac{\left(c+1\right)^{a-1}x^a}{\left(cx+1\right)^{a-1}}}\right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac {du}{dx}=\dfrac{\left(1-a\right)c\left(c+1\right)^{a-1}x^a}{\left(cx+1\right)^a}+a\left(c+1\right)^{a-1}x^{a-1}\left(cx+1\right)^{1-a}
\end{equation}

But, I always get an $x$ term messing around. Another option is  to use q-Beta functions..but it is too restrictive because $0 < q < 1$.

Comment: Let $x=u/c$.  Then it reduces to the incomplete beta function.

Comment: Surely you mean $a < 1$, if you want the integral to converge.

Comment: You're both missing a point that tripped me up as well. You end up with $u^{-a}(1+u)^{1-a}$, but you need $u^{-a}(1-u)^{1-a}$ for the beta function. I just now deleted my own response of that nature.

Comment: Once your convergence problem will be corrected, note that the usual approach is to use a change of variable such as $$t=\frac{x}{1+cx},\quad\text{or}\quad t=\frac1{1+cx}\quad\text{or}\quad t=1+cx$$ leading to incomplete Beta functions.

Comment: @CyeWaldman you fool!  Just let $u=s-1$ and it should work out.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Well, you know what they say, fools rush in.... The problem I have with your fix is that it messes up the limits of the integral. so that they are no longer consistent with the beta function. I'm working on a revised answer that I will post shortly.

Answer (score 2):

If we let $t=-cx$, $dx=dt/(-c)$, and $x^{-a}=(-c)^at^{-a}$, then

$$\int_0^1 x^{-a} (1+cx)^{1-a} \text dx=(-c)^{a-1}\int_0^{-c}t^{-a}(1-t)^{1-a}dt$$

Recalling the definition of the beta function

$$B(\nu,\mu,x)=\int_0^x t^{\nu-1}(1-t)^{\mu-1}dt,\quad \nu,\mu>0,\  x\le1$$

and blithely ignoring the obvious problem with the limits we can write

$$\int_0^1 x^{-a} (1+cx)^{1-a} \text dx=(-c)^{a-1}\text{B}(-c,1-a,2-a)$$

with the restriction that $a<1$ in order to meet the requirements on the beta function parameters. To the casual observer this may seem absurd because of the argument $-c$ in the function. I ran the original integral in Mathematica and came out with the same result, albeit with a few extra caveats. Namely,

$$
\Re(1/c) \ge 0 \  || \  \Re(1/c) \le -1 \  || \  1/c \not\in \mathbb{R}
$$

Unfortunately, I have no access to an analytically continued incomplete beta function and cannot test this out. In fact, I'm not even sure what the parallel lines mean; in computer code this usually means *or*, but there are other mathematical meanings, as well.

Comment: Looks good.  As a last note: $$B(z;a,b)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-b)_n}{n!(a+n)}z^{a+n}$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you, I think that should alleviate any problem with the negative parameter.

Comment: Thanks guys...just one more thing... to overcome the problem with negative exponents..Can you invoke the concept of "analytic continuation" for the Beta function??

Comment: Yes, it's embodied in @SimplyBeautifulArt's summation above. I've found that I have a Matlab program for the incomplete beta function with complex argument. I don't remember when I used it in the past. There's an interesting observation here. The beta function is symmetric in $a$ and $b$ but the incomplete function is not. A word to the wise....

Comment: @Philip [A quick approximation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ah3tepyozt)